# MS Access viewing the code of bottom navigations?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to edit the code of the bottom navigation buttons. I don't want to add custom buttons.

[image]

I will add two lines of code in it.

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext
Me.VendorList.Value = Me.VendorNo
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want to do. If you want to execute code when the record changes, you don't do that by editing the code behind the built-in nav buttons. You can't edit the code behind the built-in nav buttons.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes, I wanted to change the value of my list box whenever the bottom navigation is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute code when the record changes, you can use the forms `On Current` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.VendorList.Value = Me.VendorNo
End Sub
```

This also triggers when the form is loaded, which is wanted in your case I guess.